# Where should I do the rowcount when checking for existence: sql or php?

Tags: sql, count

In the case when I want to check, if a certain entry in the database exists I have two options.

I can create an sql query using COUNT() and then check, if the result is >0...

...or I can just retrieve the record(s) and then count the number of rows in the returned rowset. For example with $result->num_rows;

What's better/faster? in mysql? in general?

Comment: It might be useful if you tag your question with mysql. Didn't know this was mysql-specific before reading in the comments.

Comment: actually I wanted to know it in general and specifically, since I don't only work with mysql... I added this to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 
  FROM (SELECT 1) t 
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = 42 )
```

Just tested, works fine on MySQL v5

COUNT(*) is generally less efficient if:

1. you can have duplicates (because the
   DBMS will have to exhaustively
   search all of the records/indexes to
   give you the exact answer) or
2. have NULL entries (for the same
   reason)

If you are COUNT'ing based on a WHERE clause that is guaranteed to produce a single record (or 0) *and* the DBMS knows this (based upon UNIQUE indexes), then it ought to be just as efficient. But, it is unlikely that you will always have this condition. Also, the DBMS may not always pick up on this depending on the version and DBMS.

Counting in the application (when you don't need the row) is almost always guaranteed to be slower/worse because:

1. You have to send data to the client, the client has to buffer it and do some work
2. You may bump out things in the DBMS MRU/LRU data cache that are more important
3. Your DBMS will (generally) have to do more disk I/O to fetch record data that you will never use
4. You have more network activity

Of course, if you want to DO something with the row if it exists, then it is definitely faster/best to simply try and fetch the row to begin with!

Comment: that sounds like the best option if I wante to retrieve the data in case of existence! thank you!

Comment: would you mind adding a small paragraph about the difference of just checking on one hand and checking plus if exists retrieving on the other hand. then I would mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

YMMV, but I suspect that if you are only checking for existence, and don't need to use the retrieved data in any way, the COUNT() query will be faster.  How much faster will depend on how much data.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest is probably asking the database if something exists:

```
SELECT EXISTS ([your query here])
```

Comment: This can be MUCH faster becuase you don't care HOW MANY which saves SQL time.

Comment: And it gives the (database server) optimizer a chance to do its thing: No need to count stuff if you just need to know it's there.

Comment: You are both wrong, this method may be faster for small tables, but once you get past a certain amount of data SELECT COUNT(*) is faster.  If you have to blindly choose, pick COUNT(*) because it's fast even on large tables and equally fast on small tables.

Comment: and in my case (mysql) I have no choice since EXISTS can only be used in subqueries it seems

Comment: It seems to me that it does EXIST ;-).  The EXIST-clause of course operates on a subquery. See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377653&seqNum=8

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is checking for the existance, then

```
Select count(*) ...
```

But if you will retrieve the data if it exists, then just get the data and check it in PHP, otherwise you'll have two calls.

Answer (score 1):

For me is in the database.

Making a count(1) is faster than $result->num_rows because in the $result->num_rows you make 2 operations 1 select and a count if the select has a count is faster to get the result.
Except if you also want the information from the db.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

is the best choice, this operation is extremely fast both on small tables and large tables.  While it's possible that

```
SELECT id FROM table
```

is faster on small tables, the difference in speed will be microscopic.  But if you have a large table, this operation can be very slow.

Therefore, your best bet is to always choose to `COUNT(*) the table` (and it's faster to do `*` than it is to pick a specific `column`) as overall, it will be the fastest operation.

Comment: Now we're talking database implementations. COUNT(*) will not always be fast. In Postgresql for example, a COUNT(*) on a very large table could be quite slow. EXISTS on the other hand was made for this purpose.

Comment: it's just that as far as I can see in mysql there is no EXISTS

Comment: I would try. (I cannot myself)

Answer (score 0):

If you want raw speed, benchmark! In addition to the methods others have suggested:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE ... LIMIT 1
```

may be faster due to avoiding the subselect. Benchmark it.

Answer (score -1):

I would definitely do it in the PHP to decrease load on the database.

In order to get a count **and** get the returned rows in SQL you would have to do two queries.. a COUNT and then a SELECT

The PHP way gives you everything you need in one result object.

Comment: I do not think this will reduce the load on the database. The database has to actually get the data, and it must be transferred and transformed to PHP.  In contrast, when doing a SELECT EXISTS the database can just consult its index.